# Laravel multiple polymorphic relationship

Tags: eloquent-relationship, laravel-models, polymorphic-relationship, laravel-9

I have a database tables as followed

| Posts Table | Comments Table | Users Table | Pages Table | Likables Table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id | id |
| user_id | user_id | name | page_name | liker_id |
| content | comment | email |  | liker_type |
| created_at | created_at |  |  | likable_id |
|  |  |  |  | likable_type |

**likable_type** column in **Likables Table** may be **post** or **comment** and
**liker_type** column may be **page** or **user**.

I want to access the the collection of total likers as well as each Page or **User** from the **Post** or **Comment** models.

Similarly, I would like to get the collection of **Posts** or **Comments** that the **User** or **Page** liked.

Is it possible to have like this? How can I make the relationships for this scenario?

Comment: I think your question should be possible. What have you already tried (code) to get this working?